# Jquery/JS check email using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Emails only format with Something@u.email.com or Something@email.com have to be accept. But My code seems doesn't work. It accepts every regex. checking empty function is working(where below checking regex). Anny suggestions? Thanks you

```
$('form').form({
    on: 'blur',
    fields: {
      email: {
        identifier: 'email',
        rules: [
          {
            type: 'regExp[[a-z0-9]+@[u.]*email.com]'
            prompt: 'Please enter a valid email'
          }

        ]
      }
      email: {
        identifier: 'email',
        rules: [
          {
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: 'Please enter something for your email (debug)'
          }

        ]
      }
```

})

Answer (score 1):

To match only those two string formats, use this:

`[A-z0-9]+@(?:u\.)?email\.com`

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/MNWd93/1)

Comment: Hello It still accept every things, I think its not Regex problem,:(

Comment: You'll need to ask a separate question about your code then.

Answer (score -1):

Try following function to validate email

```
function ValidateEmail(email) {
    var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return expr.test(email);
};

if (!ValidateEmail(YourTextFieldValue)
{
alert('Invalid Email');
}
else
{
alert('valid Email');
}
```